# JAXB: XSD union type allowing ID-References and Strings?

Tags: java, moxy, jaxb2

I'm trying to specify a union schema type allowing either a string value or a reference to an existing element for usage in Jaxb. Here's an minimal example schema:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="property" >
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:attribute name="id"    type="xsd:ID" />
        <xsd:attribute name="value" type="xsd:string" />
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    
    <xsd:complexType name="customerType">
        <xsd:attribute name="property"  type="propType" />
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="propType">
         <xsd:union memberTypes="xsd:IDREF xsd:string" />
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:element name="customer" type="customerType" />
</xsd:schema>
```

Here the property attribute can contain the property value directly or reference a defined property element from the xml-document.

As union types are automatically mapped to java-Strings, I used the XmlConversion-Annotation (from this example: [EclipseLink Example](http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/moxy/special_schema_types002.htm#BABFFEHF)) to provide a mapping to the allowed schema-types. This is working perfectly for the allowed types, i.e. decimal and string values, from the example:

```html
public class CustomerCustomizer implements DescriptorCustomizer {
   @Override
   public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) throws Exception {
      XMLDirectMapping attributeMapping = new XMLDirectMapping();
      ...
      XMLUnionField unionField = new XMLUnionField();
      unionField.addSchemaType(XMLConstants.DECIMAL_QNAME);
      unionField.addSchemaType(XMLConstants.STRING_QNAME);
      ...
   }
 
}
```

I've tested this example using EclipseLink Moxy 2.5.2.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a way to provide the capability for specifying a reference in the conversion, i.e. to look whether the property attribute specifies a valid and present ID from the xml-document and if true, use this as property-value. If not, use the given string directly.

Is there a way of using ID-References in a union in EclipseLink Moxy??
Or any other suggestion how to achieve the desired behavior of having either a reference (if available in the document) or a string value for an attribute??

Thanks for any help!